# Program pauses and waits for user to hit return before finishing function

Tags: python

There is a while loop which constantly allows user input using the raw_input keyword, that input is then passed to a function called commands() which then routes the input to the command that the user specified. In this instance, Whenever I call function movement in my code, it makes the user press enter in the function and won't process the data until the user does hit enter.

Furthermore, it appears the program is returning part of code in function movement() back to the commands() function and thus is gives me the following glitch:

```
target leo2
Successful lock on Leo2
launch

Your mobile suit shifts as you begin moving towards Leo2 at coordinates [300, 100, 100]Invalid command
Type 'commands' for a list of valid commands

Distance from suit is: 200
```

As you can see, in the middle of the function it is trying to run the main whileloop from the main module, but it then goes back to running the function in the middle. Why does this occur, and how can I fix it?

My code:

Gundam2.py

```
import math

class Mobilesuits:
    #class global variables/methods here
    instances = [] #grid cords here
    names=[]



    def __init__(self,armor,speed,name,description,cockpit_description,\
                 radar_range, coordinates):
        Mobilesuits.instances.append(self)
        Mobilesuits.names.append(name)
        self.armor=armor
        self.speed=speed
        self.name=name
        self.description=description
        self.cockpit_description=cockpit_description
        self.radar_range=radar_range
        self.coordinates=coordinates

        #Intrinsically links mobile suits objects to their names.
        #I want to be able to access each object directly through the name

    def update_names(self): 
        Mobilesuit_names_instances_dictionary={}
        for i in range(len(Mobilesuits.instances)):
            Mobilesuit_names_instances_dictionary[Mobilesuits.names[i]] =Mobilesuits.instances[i]
        return Mobilesuit_names_instances_dictionary








    def can_detect(self, other):
        for own_coord, other_coord in zip(self.coordinates, other.coordinates):
            if abs(own_coord - other_coord) > self.radar_range:
                return False
            return True

    def radar(self):
        for other in Mobilesuits.instances:
            if other is not self  and self.can_detect(other):
                print "%s detected at %s" % (other.description, other.coordinates)

    def movement(self, target, official_target, currentmobilesuit):
        print("Your mobile suit shifts as you begin moving towards %s at coordinates %s" %(target,official_target.coordinates))

        distance = (currentmobilesuit.coordinates[0] - official_target.coordinates[0],\
                          currentmobilesuit.coordinates[1] - official_target.coordinates[1], \
                          currentmobilesuit.coordinates[2]-official_target.coordinates[2])

        calculation=0
        for i in distance:
            calculation += abs(i)
        print("Distance from suit is: %s" % (calculation))




        #Make speed calculation based on distance away and speed of suit
        #Errors:
        #target without a suit gives error
```

maingundam.py

```
from Gundam2 import Mobilesuits
import thread
import time

#Main Variable/Object declarations:

Leo1=Mobilesuits(100,100,"Leo1","leo desc","dockpit desc",100,[100,100,100])
Leo2=Mobilesuits(100,100,"Leo2","leo desc","dockpit desc",100,[300,100,100])
Leo3=Mobilesuits(100,100,"Leo3","leo desc","dockpit desc",100,[100,150,100])
currentmobilesuit=Leo1
mobile_suit_names_list=currentmobilesuit.update_names()

#Main Function declarations               
def commands(user_input,currentmobilesuit, mobile_suit_names_list):

    #radar
    if user_input == "radar":
        currentmobilesuit.radar()

    #Commands overview    
    elif user_input == "commands":
        print("Command list:\nradar\ntarget (object)")

    #Target objects
    elif user_input.startswith("target"):
        try:
            global target
            target=user_input.split()[1].title()
            if mobile_suit_names_list[target]:
                global official_target
                official_target=mobile_suit_names_list[target]
                print("Successful lock on %s" % (target))
        except:
            print("space object '%s' not detected" %(target))


    elif user_input=="launch":
       # try:
        if official_target:
            thread.start_new_thread(currentmobilesuit.movement, (target, official_target, currentmobilesuit))
       # except:
        #    print("No target is selected")

     #command not found
    else:
        print("Invalid command\nType 'commands' for a list of valid commands")

def active_delay(action, delay):
    time.sleep(delay)
    action()





#Main execution: paused
while True:
    mobile_suit_names_list=currentmobilesuit.update_names()
    commands(raw_input(),currentmobilesuit,mobile_suit_names_list)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your second problem is that, if your user *just* hits <kbd>Return</kbd>, the return from `raw_input` is an empty string `""`, which is not handled by `command()`. You could fix this by adding the lines:

```
elif user_input == "":
    pass
```

Your first problem is due to the way `raw_input` works; it always waits for user input followed by <kbd>Return</kbd> and is *not* designed for being used for continuous control input. This is trickier to fix. You might be better using a library designed for this sort of thing (continuous keyboard control), like [`pygame`](http://www.pygame.org/news.html).

Comment: Thanks mate. Appreciate you looking through all that code and helping me